# Understanding formula for the standardized selection ratio (SSR)

Tags: interaction, biostatistics

Manyl et al defined an index called Standardized Selection Ratio (SSR). [Here](http://books.google.ch/books?hl=fr&lr=&id=hNy8aM8HmrwC&oi=fnd&pg=PR9&dq=Statistical+design+and+analysis+for+field+studies&ots=e3F4Z714o0&sig=ULzWk1pfmm2vkrbb6nK2YKEAYms#v=onepage&q=standardized%20selection%20ratio&f=false) is the source. I don't quite understand how this index is calculated and how the p.values are calculated. Can you help me. The interesting part starts at page 40 (and ends few pages after) of the book.

Below is an example of an article where this index was used. They described the SSR index but it doesn't make much sense to me either.

---

On [this article](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10641-010-9606-0#page-1) they used the Standardized Selection Ratio (SSR) in order to know what is the preferred host (anemone) of anemonefish.

Here is a quotation coming from their methods:

> The “preferred host” of anemonefish was assessed calculating the “Standardized
>       Selection Ratio (SSR)” (values between 0 and 1) (Manly et al. 1993). Manly’s standardized
>       selection ratio represents the probability that an individual will use a particular habitat
>       type, taking into account the different resource availability. For each anemonefish species ($i$) inhabiting an anemone species ($j$), SSR was calculated as:

$$SSR = \frac{w_i}{\sum{w_j}} $$

where $w_i = \frac{o_i}{p_j}$

> $o_i$ is the relative frequency of the anemonefish species $i$ and $p_j$ the relative frequency
>       of the anemone species $j$. Higher values of SSR indicate a strong preference for the
>       selected resource. The Log- Likelihood statistic ($\chi^2$L) (Manly et al. 1993) was used to
>       check the significance of the observed distribution under a null hypothesis of a random
>       host choice.

Comment: You wrote "For each anemonefish species ($i$) inhabiting an anemone species ($j$), SSR was calculated as: $SSR = \frac{w_i}{\sum{w_j}}$".  Is it SSR(i) or SSR(i,j) ?  Which of those is correct: (a) each a-fish inhabits exactly one anemone, and each anemone is inhabited by exactly one a-fish -or- (b) each a-fish inhabits exactly one anemone, and each anemone is inhabited by one or more a-fishes -or- (c) each a-fish inhabits one or more anemones, and each anemone is inhabited by one or more a-fishes -or- (d) something else ?

Comment: @user31264 I don't quite know. I was citing an article that used this SSR index that I don't understand. I guess that each anemone way inhabited by one or more fishes. I guess the important part to understand this index is the book from Manly et al but I can't understand it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user31264 Let me rephrase it. I would actually bet that they considered that there is never two fishes for one anemone. I guess that for each anemone there is one fish and for each fish there is one anemone.